# How can I fix the redirect the link in the new browser issue?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, redirect

Right now, I can do the redirect my website from IE11 to Chrome. But if I open and click the redirect link in Chrome, it doesn't response and just showing Redirecting. How can I fix that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Redirecting</title>
<h1>Browser Redirect</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
{ varshell = new AciveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.run("Chrome //"link example//");
window.location.replace("Old link in the previous browser"):}
setTimeot("pageRedirect()",3000);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: I created [a simple demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8ugV.png) and try to reproduce your issue but failed, it works well. If possible, could you provide more details? For example, are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: Ok i will test it out and will get back to you

Comment: Still happening, If I do it from IE, it redirect to chrome. But if I reclick the same link and open in Chrome, it doesn't show.

Comment: As I mentioned, are there any error messages in the console? You can also try to clear the browser cache.

Comment: If the purpose of this it to switch browser to Chrome, why are you using this code for a Chrome browser, they ALREADY ARE IN CHOME.